# error: ‘asm’ operand requires impossible reload при сборе ядра

Tags: linux, kernel

Следовал по инструкции:

Для начала установил нужные мне пакеты - `fakeroot, kernel-package`

Скачал само [ядро](https://github.com/SolidRun/linux-imx6-3.14)

Настроил его так, как мне нужно, и ввел следующую команду:

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --revision=custom.1.0 kernel_image
```

Как прошло некоторое время, в консоли вылезла такая ошибка:

```
fs/btrfs/scrub.c: In function ‘scrub_enumerate_chunks’:
/root/linux-linaro-stable-mx6/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h:283:2: error: ‘asm’ operand requires impossible reload
make[3]: *** [fs/btrfs/scrub.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [fs/btrfs] Error 2
make[1]: *** [fs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/linux-linaro-stable-mx6'
make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: так это у вас кросс-компиляция? а *toolchain* откуда брали?

Comment: да кросс, toolchain уже был установлен.

Comment: не [этот](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-linaro/+bug/942307) ли, случайно?

Comment: самой существенной информации вы в вопросе и не указали: ни то, что это кросс-компиляция, ни откуда вы взяли исходники (или бинарники) toolchain-а, ни как их собирали, ни как настраивали сборку на использование этого toolchain-а, ни какой конфиг для linux-а использовали.

Comment: Про кросс-компиляцию да, забыл упомянуть. сборка линукса уже с toolchain´ом, настроена также не мною.